# How do i show the image in only comments that the user has uploaded on in, on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, comments

i wanted to show the comments from the database which i did however i also wanted to add the image of the comment if the user uploaded one, currently i store the images in a folder and the image path is on the database next to the comments if the user added a image with thier comment, however it is not showing the image and its also making image spaces where comments that didnt have images are, the code is below

```
<?php
   include('../c_database.php');

   $queryAll = "SELECT ID, Username, Comments, time_added FROM comments ORDER BY ID DESC";

   $executeQuery = mysqli_query($dbc, $queryAll);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($executeQuery)){

   echo '<div class="commentbox">';
   echo '<div class="comments">';
   echo '<fieldset class="comment">';
   echo '<legend>';
   echo $row['Username'];
   echo '</legend>';
   echo '<br>'; 
   echo '<br>'; 
   echo '<img src="'.$row['imagepath'].'" width="100px" height="100px"></img>';
   echo '&nbsp'; 
   echo $row['Comments']; 
   echo '<br>';
   echo '<br>';
   echo '<div class="commentdetails">';
   echo '<fieldset>';
   echo $row['time_added'];
   echo ' / '; 
   echo 'Comment ID: ';
   echo $row['ID'];  
   echo '</div>'; 
   echo '</fieldset>';
   echo '</div>';
   echo '<br>';
   echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

so how do i show the image in only comments that the users has uploaded on?

Answer (score 0):

Well if the user has or can upload only one profile image, then when uploading the file into a directory rename the file with the user session id like: `$image_name = $_SESSION['user']`
Then if the user's session `id = 1` then profile image will be like `1.jpg`

Now, when showing the picture, you can call up the image using the users id.

It is a weak approach, but I created once a site with which a user only can upload one picture, and it worked.

In your code, you could do

`echo '<img src="uploads/$_SESSION['user'].jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></img>'`

or 
`echo '<img src="user.php?id=$id.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></img>'`

Comment: If you found the answer you were looking for, make sure to vote it as best answer, otherwise feel free to ask for more help

Comment: Hi, i thanks for answer i just got home but the system will show comments with a image if the user uploaded one, its not a profile image system, its meant to show all the images that each comment attached with an image is supposed to

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your query. You have pointed all columns that you will need in the table except imagepath in you SELECT statement. If I understand correctly you have imagepath in your comments table? If this is the case then you need to do next: 
Instead `echo '<img src="'.$row['imagepath'].'" width="100px" height="100px"></img>';`
Do `echo  (!empty($row['imagepath'])) ? '<img src="'.$row['imagepath'].'" width="100px" height="100px"></img>' : '';`.